# Problems creating a custom UIView

Tags: iphone, uiview, custom-controls

I'm trying to create my own UIView subclass. I've placed it on my view in Interface Builder by dragging out a UIView, then specifying my subclass's name in the Class Identity field. Yet my UIView does not draw itself.

Here--in a simplified example--is the code in my UIView subclass:

```
- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder
{
    if (self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder])
    {
        UILabel* label = [[[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:self.frame] autorelease];
        label.text = @"Hello.";
        label.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
        [self addSubview:label];        
    }

    return self;
}
```

I've seen reference to overriding drawRect:, but honestly I have no idea what I'd do in that method. I'm sure I'm doing something obviously wrong, but I have no idea what.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `self.bounds` instead of `self.frame`:

```
UILabel* label = [[[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:self.bounds] autorelease];
```

Your view's frame is probably not at origin {0 0}, which means that the label would end up outside your view's visible area.